# Unable to pass querystring within asp.net anchor tag

Tags: asp.net, database

I'm getting data from a database, and one of them its a link to a picture somewhere in the web.
I want the user to click on that link, and then with querystring, to pass all the data to another page.

I tried to do this :

```
<% foreach (System.Data.DataRow dataRow in DT.Rows ) { %>                           
<% = dataRow["Title"].ToString() %>
<% string QueryString= Request.QueryString.ToString(); %>
<a href="<%("MoviesInfo.aspx?"+ QueryString)  %>"><img src="<% = dataRow["Descreption"].ToString() %>" width="30%" height="30%" /></a>
<% = dataRow["Ganere"].ToString() %>

<% } %>
```

but it didnt work out well...
what could be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code.

1) You're setting QueryString to be the current Request's query string. I'm pretty sure you want this be data on the current row?

```
<% string QueryString= dataRow["Movie"].ToString(); %>
```

2) The href should be built using `<%=` instead of `<%`:

```
<a href="<%= ("MoviesInfo.aspx?"+ QueryString)  %>">
```